# React Native pod install failed on Apple Silicon (M1)

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, apple-silicon, apple-m1

I got my new Macbook Pro which has M1 chip.

I tried to run my react native project but stucked on **pod install.**

After that, I created an empty project and tried on that still getting the same error.

````
### Command

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/bin/pod install
```

### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.10.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.arm64e-darwin20]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3
        Host : macOS 11.0.1 (20B29)
       Xcode : 12.4 (12D4e)
         Git : git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : 
```

### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.5.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```

### Podfile

```ruby
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'temp2' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  target 'temp2Tests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'temp2-tvOS' do
  # Pods for temp2-tvOS

  target 'temp2-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

### Error

```
LoadError - dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): missing compatible arch in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:74:in `cdn_url?'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:36:in `create_source_with_url'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:21:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `block in sources'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `map'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `sources'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1073:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1072:in `resolve_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=dlopen%28%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%2C+0x0009%29%3A+missing+compatible+arch+in+%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle+-+%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
 - Couldn't determine repo type for URL: `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`: Invalid ABI specified
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10368 [open] [2 comments]
   a week ago

 - CocoaPods compatibility with Apple DTK (Apple Silicon)
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9907 [open] [75 comments]
   15 hours ago

 - Firebase installation error on xcode 12 com m1 processor
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10329 [closed] [4 comments]
   12 hours ago

and 3 more at:
https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=dlopen%28%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%2C%200x0009%29%3A%20missing%20compatible%20arch%20in%20%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%20-%20%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle&type=Issues&utf8=✓
````

After I make research about this topic I found several solutions but still my problem is not solved.

I already tried to install

```
sudo gem install ffi
```

and then tried **pod install** again. Still getting same error.

After that according to my research some people said to use terminal with rosetta or the another way to rosetta,

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

with these Intel based installation try I'm getting below error:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
[!] Couldn't determine repo type for URL: `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`: Invalid ABI specified
```

Did somebody faced with this problem? What I'm doing wrong or what I need to do to run my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that homebrew installation messed up cocoapods.

Simply, I uninstalled homebrew and start from beginning. Then it worked.

Answer (score 13):

for homebrew users

step 1 `brew install cocoapods`
step 2 `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`
step 3 `arch -x86_64 pod install`

fixed my issue

Comment: This answer saved my 2 days. This worked for me 10000% perfectly. Thank you very much

Comment: Does this mean .. I will need to use `arch -x86_64 pod install` every time i want to do `pod install` in the future?

Comment: yes @AungMyintThein
but there is another solution for this
use rosetta terminal

Answer (score 10):

My problem with ffi resolved with just `brew install cocoapods` =)

*Firstly I tried to install from `bundler` and there was a specific old version of cocoapods which didn't support m1 yet; then I used brew and now with the latest cocoapods it works fine*

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it preserves the ability to use homebrew. I didn't try the accepted answer because I didn't want to completely scrap homebrew just for the sake of RN so I don't know if it works, but this _did_ work for me.

Answer (score 4):

My problem was installing cocoapods with `gem` (which most tutorials online will tell you). Try uninstalling cocoapods with the following command:

```
gem uninstall cocoapods
```

Then install it again using brew

```
brew install cocoapods
```

homebrew installed the arm64 version, while gem seems to default to something else.

Comment: Thank you, for me this is the correct way and the best!

Answer (score 3):

This resource helped me: https://www.lopau.com/error-running-cocoapod-pod-install-on-big-sur-with-ffi/

Run `sudo gem inst ffi -- --disable-system-libffi`

Comment: This worked successfully for me while running pod update when upgrading react native .64 to .65

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me: (M1 Pro)

```
arch -x86_64 sudo gem install cocoapods
arch -x86_64 pod repo update
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

sources: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10349

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue on M1 chip MacBook. Finally did the below

In rosetta terminal :

```
-- sudo rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos
```

Inside iOS folder

```
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution for me was to init the app like this

```
arch -x86_64 npx react-native init awsomeproject
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest version of Xcode from App Store, and then run these two commands in the Terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that CocoaPod flipper was out of date. The change in the pod file from

```
 use_flipper()!
```

to

```
use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.95.0', 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.6.7', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.4.3', 'Flipper-DoubleConversion' => '3.1.7', 'Flipper-Glog' => '0.3.9', 'Flipper-PeerTalk' => '0.0.4' })
```

helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Mac M1 architecture is not directly compatible with Cocoapods. If you encounter issues when installing pods, you can solve it by running:

- `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`
- `arch -x86_64 pod install`

These commands install the `ffi` package, to load dynamically-linked libraries and let you run the `pod install` properly, and runs `pod install` with the proper architecture.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this command worked

`arch -x86_64 pod install`

Answer (score 0):

XCode ruined installation

```
npm ERR! Couldn't install Pods. Updating the Pods project and trying again...
npm ERR! Command `pod install` failed.
npm ERR! └─ Cause: /bin/bash -c
```

So I reset XCode command-line tools by run

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

hope it helps someone too )