# Pod install fails on m1 macbook

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, flutter-ios

Error in running pod install.
I've been trying to run pod install but it keeps failing on all projects, I even created new projects from scratch to eliminate the suspicion that it might be an error in the configuration but it also failed .
I've tried gem cocoapods and brew cocoapods, I've also tried with and without arch -x86_64 but nothing works  I've also tried everything in these links:
[React Native pod install failed on Apple Silicon (M1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65917288/react-native-pod-install-failed-on-apple-silicon-m1)

```
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `boost` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Downloading dependencies
Installing CocoaAsyncSocket (7.6.5)
Installing DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
Installing FBLazyVector (0.67.4)
Installing FBReactNativeSpec (0.67.4)
Installing Flipper (0.99.0)
Installing Flipper-Boost-iOSX (1.76.0.1.11)
Installing Flipper-DoubleConversion (3.1.7)
Installing Flipper-Fmt (7.1.7)
Installing Flipper-Folly (2.6.7)
Installing Flipper-Glog (0.3.6)
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
#
# This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.

set -e

PLATFORM_NAME="${PLATFORM_NAME:-iphoneos}"
CURRENT_ARCH="${CURRENT_ARCH}"

if [ -z "$CURRENT_ARCH" ] || [ "$CURRENT_ARCH" == "undefined_arch" ]; then
    # Xcode 10 beta sets CURRENT_ARCH to "undefined_arch", this leads to incorrect linker arg.
    # it's better to rely on platform name as fallback because architecture differs between simulator and device

    if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" == *"simulator"* ]]; then
        CURRENT_ARCH="x86_64"
    else
        CURRENT_ARCH="armv7"
    fi
fi

export CC="$(xcrun -find -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME cc) -arch $CURRENT_ARCH -isysroot $(xcrun -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME --show-sdk-path)"
export CXX="$CC"

# Remove automake symlink if it exists
if [ -h "test-driver" ]; then
    rm test-driver
fi

./configure --host arm-apple-darwin

# Fix build for tvOS
cat << EOF >> src/config.h
/* Add in so we have Apple Target Conditionals */
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#include <Availability.h>
#endif
/* Special configuration for AppleTVOS */
#if TARGET_OS_TV
#undef HAVE_SYSCALL_H
#undef HAVE_SYS_SYSCALL_H
#undef OS_MACOSX
#endif
/* Special configuration for ucontext */
#undef HAVE_UCONTEXT_H
#undef PC_FROM_UCONTEXT
#if defined(__x86_64__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__rip
#elif defined(__i386__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__eip
#endif
EOF

# Prepare exported header include
EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR="exported/glog"
mkdir -p exported/glog
cp -f src/glog/log_severity.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/raw_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/stl_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/vlog_is_on.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /opt/homebrew/bin/ginstall -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /opt/homebrew/bin/gmkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc... /Applications/Developer Tools/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Developer Tools/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk
checking whether the C compiler works... no
/Users/samimishal/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/Users/samimishal/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
configure: error: in `/Users/samimishal/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: Did you remember to install your own Ruby? The built-in system Ruby is unusable on M1.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18408 or https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29203

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having this issue on an M1 mac and did the following:

1. Installed my own version of ruby via homebrew: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66556339/436014 and set the paths accordingly (I had to adjust the path for the pods because I installed ruby 3.1.0 not 3.0.0) This was critical for me, it wasn't working otherwise.
2. In Xcode `Preferences > Location`, my `Command Line Tools` setting was empty. I clicked the dropdown and set it accordingly.
   [image: xcode preferences]
3. I completely cleaned everything (be careful running these commands). In project root: `rm -fr node_modules && watchman watch-del-all && yarn && cd ios && rm -rf Pods && pod cache clean --all && pod install && cd ..`
4. Finally the app was able to build and run on my M1 mac without using Rosetta at all

Comment: I've already tried this, but it doesn't work

Comment: In my case I had installed cocoapods using brew 3.0+, which supports M1 so I didn't have an issue with Ruby but your step 2 was my issue, just need to set command line tools in Xcode.  Also didn't need to blow away everything after that, just did pod install again.

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure but this might help. Go to Finder => Applications => Utilities => Terminal => Right Click => Get Info => Check "Open using Rosetta" => Reopen the terminal and try again

Comment: I've already tried this, but it doesn't work