# Cocoapods gem not being properly recognized on M1 Mac

Tags: ios, ruby, react-native, apple-m1

I'm trying to run the React Native [Environment Setup](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) guide.
Once inside the directory created by `npx react-native init` command, I try to install the `cocoapods` gem as instructed. It install successfully, and when I run `which pod`, I get

```bash
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/bin/pod
```

The issue is when I try to run any `pod` commands, like `pod -v` or `pod install`. It behaves like I don't have that gem installed and outputs this:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
    3: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
    2: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    1: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:296:in `activate_bin_path'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:277:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem cocoapods (>= 0.a) with executable pod (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

I have no idea why I'm getting that.
I see that the `pod` bin is inside the `ruby-2.7.4/bin/` folder, and on the last line of  the error above, it looks inside the `ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb`. I don't understand how the gems are handled very well, so I'm not sure if that's related. I appreciate any help.

Machine: Mac Mini M1.
OS: Mac OS Monterey 12.4.
RVM version: 1.29.12.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native pod install failed on Apple Silicon (M1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65917288/react-native-pod-install-failed-on-apple-silicon-m1)

Comment: I doesn't :( I tried using the homebrew `cocoapods`, but with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. These are the steps I took:

1. Skip the `sudo gem install cocoapods` command recommended in the docs. Since I use RVM, it would install the gem on the global Ruby instead of the project's one.
2. When initializing the React Native project, the CLI will ask to install `cocoapods`. Hit ESC to cancel.
3. Navigate inside the project folder, install the required Ruby version (if necessary) and run `bundle install`. It will install the required `cocoapods` version.
4. After that, `pod --help` or `pod install` should work. Keep in mind the `pod install` should be executed from the `ios/` folder inside your project.

Please notice that I didn't have to make anything specific to the M1 processor at this time. I just installed everything normally from my default arm64 terminal.

Comment: "Since I use RVM, it would install the gem on the global Ruby instead of the project's one" But that suggests that RVM was installed incorrectly. The whole point of RVM is that you say `gem install` and the correct `gem` installs in the correct `ruby`.

Comment: The thing is that when I run the `npx react-native init <project>` command, as recommended on the docs, it will try to install cocoapods automatically. At that point, if I didn't have the project's Ruby version installed (currently 2.7.4, and I didn't since there was no way to know which version the generated project would use), the gem would be installed under the global version instead. That's why I needed to skip that automatic installation, install the correct Ruby, and then run `bundle install` after that.